# How to subtract dynamic row result using Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table.

[image]

In this table Month row is dynamic

I want to get the following input,

[image]

Anybody knows the solution to get the output.

Comment: If it has more rows( for example 100 rows) how your logical output will be?

Comment: where do you get the values for row C?

Comment: I need to get new row. Instead of C you can use any text. Month value is dynamic

Comment: Hi Kannan, 
C= (B-A) . Even if have 100 column also i want to subtract B row - A row . 
Instead of C you can use any text.

Comment: how about 100 rows ? not 100 columns

Comment: How A and B are connected? How do you know, that those are related?

Comment: that's what i meant, the values for the new row, how do you get them? are they all coming from the difference between two previous rows? like c = b-a, then d would be c-b?

Comment: Hi rigerta, 
I am going to display only 4 rows (Month, A , B, C).

Comment: Hi Rigerta, 
Row count is fixed (I am going to display only 4 rows including header). Column is dynamic. 
I am getting A and B row result, using different dynamic query. After that i am using union all to merge the data and insert into temp table. Now i want to subtract B with A . For that new row use can use any name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
select Month, [2017-04], [2017-03], [2017-02], [2017-01]
from your_Table
where Month in ('A', 'B')

union all

select
    'C'
    T1.[2017-04] - T2.[2017-04], 
    T1.[2017-03] - T2.[2017-03], 
    T1.[2017-02] - T2.[2017-02], 
    T1.[2017-01] - T2.[2017-03]
from your_Table as T1
    left outer join your_Table as T2 on T2.Month = 'A'
where T1.Month = 'B'
```

Comment: Andy, this will not work if there are 100 rows on the table...upvoted because the logic is right.

Comment: @rigerta Surely it will not. But OP mentioned in comments that desired result should be subtraction of data with two specified rows, B and A. It looks strange - but this was original requirement: *"Even if have 100 column also i want to subtract B row - A row"*

Comment: Yes Correct. [2017-04], [2017-03], [2017-02], [2017-01] these values are dynamic. I want to subtract B row - A row

Answer (score 0):

Extremely strange question but:

```
SELECT Month
     , [2017-04]
     , [2017-03] 
     , [2017-02]
     , [2017-01]  
FROM (
  SELECT Month
     , [2017-04]
     , [2017-03] 
     , [2017-02]
     , [2017-01] 
     , 1 as mOrder
  FROM  table 
  WHERE Month in ('B','A')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C'
     , sum(case Month = 'A' then [2017-04]*-1 else [2017-04] end)
     , sum(case Month = 'A' then [2017-03]*-1 else [2017-04] end)
     , sum(case Month = 'A' then [2017-02]*-1 else [2017-04] end)
     , sum(case Month = 'A' then [2017-01]*-1 else [2017-04] end)
     , 2 as morder
  FROM table 
  WHERE Month in ('B','A')
  )
ORDER BY Month, mOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you will need to add rows dynamically and the check should be always done with the previous row, so I would use the following code:

```
 insert into dbo.tab1 
 select 'C' as month
       , t.[2017-04] - tprev.[2017-04] as [2017-04]
       , t.[2017-03] - tprev.[2017-03] as [2017-03]
       , t.[2017-02] - tprev.[2017-02] as [2017-02]
       , t.[2017-01] - tprev.[2017-01] as [2017-01]
 from ( 
         select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY month) AS Nr
             , month
             , [2017-04]
             , [2017-03]
             , [2017-02]
             , [2017-01] 
         from dbo.tab1 
       ) t left join (
                 select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY month) AS Nr
                    , month
                    , [2017-04]
                    , [2017-03]
                    , [2017-02]
                    , [2017-01] 
                from dbo.tab1 
           ) tprev on t.Nr = (tprev.Nr -1) -- join with prev row to get the difference
```

You could add this inside a loop where you generate the Month value beforehand and pass it here is a parameter. 
I generated the row number and joined on it, because if you have more than the first two rows, you will need an additional column to join. 
You can check a working version of this [here](http://rextester.com/UGN80124).